# Perform link label click with key press

Tags: c#, events, event-handling, keypress

I'm trying to create an event for a link label when the 'A' key is pressed.  and the same when 'B' key is pressed, and so on until 'Z'.  The name of the linklabel is ALinkLabel

From what I've researched, I think it would look a bit something like this

```
private void ALinkLabel_KeyPressed(object sender, KeyEventArg e)
{
   something in there
}
```

I'm not exactly sure, new to C#.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated

Comment: does the label have tab stop? can it receive focus at run time? its not a input control like textbox - so not sure. Will try a simple app and post my answer later.


http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.label.keypress.aspx

Comment: What are you actually trying to do with this piece of code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are going to instead want to handle the KeyPressed on the parent form / user control and then use the [`PerformClick`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb337532.aspx) of the appropriate LinkLabel after casting it to IButtonControl.

In order to find the matching LinkLabel you might consider storing the bound letter in the link label control's `Tag` property.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are trying to change text of a label when keys are pressed or something!

refer here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/da-DK/winforms/thread/b2c7bdd0-6204-4ced-b3d9-6101925b06ed